# malloc and C alignment: is this hand-made optimization safe?

Tags: c, memory-alignment

I put the whole code but, of course, it's in different files (`.h` and `.c` files)

```
typedef unsigned char ubyte;
typedef unsigned int uint;
#include<stdbool.h>

typedef struct Cube {
    ubyte n;
    ubyte e;
    ubyte s;
    ubyte w;
} Cube;

typedef struct Piece {
    Cube c;
    bool is_main;
    char offset_n;
    char offset_s;
} Piece;

typedef struct Block {
    ubyte total;
    Piece* pieces;
} Block;

Block *block_create(uint nb_pieces) {
    Block *block = malloc(sizeof(Block) + (sizeof(Piece) * nb_pieces));
    block->pieces = (Piece *) (&block + sizeof(Block));
    return block;
}
```

I am just wondering if this line of code: `block->pieces = (&block + sizeof(Block));` will be **always** safe. I mean: can we be sure that, *immediately* after the `sizeof(Piece)`, we will have precisely `(sizeof(Piece) * nb_pieces)`? Are we sure there will never be an alignment problem (ie maybe if it's 64-bits aligned, the memory for `sizeof(Block)` will be less than 8 bytes and the `block->pieces` should *not* point to exactly `sizeof(Block)`, but "`sizeof(Block)` 64 bits-aligned").

I hope I'm clear enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, this isn't doing what you expect, and for multiple reasons:

```
block->pieces = (&block + sizeof(Block));
```

First, `&block` is the address of the variable `block`, not the contents of `block`, and has type `block **`.  At most, you can safely add 1 this pointer value because anything more will create a pointer past the end of this variable which is invalid.

So then you would need to change `&block` to `block`.  That still won't do what you expect because pointer arithmetic increments the raw address by multiples of the object size.  So adding `sizeof(Block)` to this is not moving up 1 array element but moving up `sizeof(Block)` array elements.

To fix this you would need `block + 1`.  Now you need to start worrying about alignment.  For your array of `Pieces` to be aligned properly, you would need to check if `_Alignof(Block)` and `_Alignof(Piece)` are the same.  If not, you would need to add padding bytes:

```
int padding = 0;
if (_Alignof(Block) % _Alignof(Piece) != 0) {
    padding = _Alignof(Piece) - (_Alignof(Block) % _Alignof(Piece));
}
Block *block = malloc(sizeof(Block) + padding + (sizeof(Piece) * nb_pieces));
block->pieces = (Piece *)((char *)(block + 1) + padding);
```

Of course, you can avoid all this by making the `pieces` member a *flexible array member*:

```
typedef struct Block {
    ubyte total;
    Piece pieces[];
} Block;
```

And the allocation by itself will be enough.

Comment: Thank you very much indeed for your detailed answer! May I ask you to add a sample of a simple allocation for your last suggestion? I stopped doing C ~10 years ago, but I'm so fed up of slow languages and languages where the problem is almost always not you but the library you use (Node, Python, etc.) that I want *again* to do all on my own. If there's a problem, I will be sure it's 100% my fault this time **`;^)`** . So I have to re-work on pointers, but I guess that it wont be harder than trying to debug someone else's poorly written code!

Comment: @OlivierPons The allocation is the same. `sizeof(Block)` does not include the flexible array member but does include any necessary padding between the FLA member and the prior member.